# Inject field of class that is instantiated before the Dagger Component

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a class `A` with a field `private SomeValue someValue`. My Dagger `@Component` class is called `MyApplicationComponent`.

The class `A` is instantiated before `DaggerMyApplicationComponent`. Therefore, I don't know how to inject `someValue`.

I can't use constructor injection because `A` is created before the component.

I believe I can't use field injection either because in `A` I would need to call `MyApplicationComponent.inject(this)`, but in `A` I have no idea when `MyApplicationComponent` will be instantiated so I don't know when to call `.inject`.

I tried using setter injection, by adding this method to `A`:

```
@Inject
public void setSomeValue(SomeValue someValue) {
    log.info("in setter injector!");
    this.someValue = someValue;
}
```

Also, I added this to `MyApplicationComponent`:

```
void inject(A a);
```

However, the setter method is never called.

Why is this method not called?

How does Dagger do setter injection?

Is there some way to tell Dagger to inject `someValue` into `A` once `DaggerMyApplicationComponent` has been instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

With method injection, when objects are instantiated, dagger invokes methods that are annotated with @inject annotation once. which means it's not what you need. you can define a generic interface that your component interface (MyApplicationComponent) extend it.

```
interface Injector<T> {
    void inject(T instance);
}


public interface MyApplicationComponent extends Injector<A>{

    MyApplicationComponent getMyApplicationComponent();

    void inject(A instance);
}
```

Then create a method in your class, like this:

```
public class A {


    private SomeValue someValue

    public void setSomeValue(Injector<A> com) {
       com.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Finally when ur component is created, invoke setSomeValue method and pass component object to it.

```
A obj=new A();

MyApplicationComponent component=DaggerMyApplicationComponent.create();

obj.setSomeValue(component);
```